# How to jquery if scroll echo div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```css
#main {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  background: green
}
.menu1 {
  height: 30px;
  background: red
}
.menu2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="menu1">COntent 1</div>
  <div class="menu2">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

How to: When I'm scroll down div `.menu2` display sticky in top as css

```
.menu2 {
  height: 30px; background: blue; position: fixed
}
```

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/rh1aLnxs/

Thanks

Comment: I suggest u to use plug-in:http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/zepto_onepage_scroll_demo.html

Comment: @Kermani Thanks but it's not my code

Answer (score 1):

this can be accomplished with css's position:fixed, as long as you don't need additional behavior regarding the parent div (position:fixed is ignorant to the parent in css)

here's an example:

```
.menu1 {position:fixed; height: 30px; background: red; max-width: 500px; width:100%}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rh1aLnxs/

If you need for example, for menu1 to go away when the user scrolls below main, then you need to use jquery's scroll event and handle the positioning manually (http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Comment: default `.menu2` display: none. i want: When I'm scroll down div `.menu2` display sticky in top.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
  var headerTop = $('.menu1').offset().top;
       // var headerBottom = headerTop + 120; // Sub-menu should appear after this distance from top.
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // Current vertical scroll position from the top
            if (scrollTop > headerTop) { // Check to see if we have scrolled more than headerBottom
                if (($(".menu2").is(":visible") === false)) {
     $('.menu1').hide();
                    $('.menu2').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            } else {
                if ($(".menu2").is(":visible")) {
     
                    $('.menu2').hide();
      $('.menu1').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            }
        });
```

```css
#main {
 max-width: 500px;
 height: 900px;
 margin: auto;
 background: green
}
.menu1 {
 height: 30px;
 background-color: red
}
.menu2 {
 background-color: blue;
 max-width: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 display: none;
 /*display: none*/
 position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="menu1">Content1</div>
  <div class="menu2">Content2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some improvements on your fiddle along with a simplified version of the script to add/remove a fixed class on scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/rh1aLnxs/2/

```js
jQuery(window).bind("scroll", function() {
 if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
  jQuery(".menu1").removeClass("no-fixed").addClass("fixed");
   } else {
  jQuery(".menu1").removeClass("fixed").addClass("no-fixed");
   }
  });
```

```css
#main {max-width: 500px; height: 900px; margin: auto; background: green}
.menu1 {height: 30px; background: red}
.menu2 {display: none}

#main {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.no-fixed {
    position: relative;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu2"></div>
</div>
```